# Prevent a control table from getting new dates for the same day - Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, teradata, teradatasql

I have a proc that loads a new date and time into a control table each day. Sometimes the proc may get ran again but I want to prevent that control table from getting a new date entry again if we are in the same day. What SQL code can I use to prevent it from getting new dates if it is the same day in Teradata?

Expecting: Control table does not get a new date entry if we are in the same day.

Comment: Make the date the PK for the table?

Comment: Use a MERGE instead of INSERT

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I need an If statement or code for Teradata that would skip running a procedure if there is an insert for today's date already in a control table. 

If control table has an insert for todays date, skip running proc.

Comment: As this is not a code writing service, please update your question with what you’ve managed to write for yourself and ask a question about a specific issue you are facing